# Is this a memory leak or unreleased resources

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not quite sure if this is a memory leak or if the resources are not being released for GC, but it looks suspect since I'm referencing a property from another object.

I deserialize an XML file into an object. I then use this object to populate some properties of another object. Does doing this keep this deserialized-file-into-a-class-object in memory somewhere:

```
 void Load() {
   MyClass deserializedClass = Helper.GetDeserializedFileFromXml(path, type);
   SetProperty(deserializedClass)
 }

 // MyProperty is a List<ADifferentClass>;
 void SetProp(MyClass myClass) {
    MyProperty = myClass.MyProperty;
 }
```

**UPDATE**

I realized after reading the comments below that the crucial part (and why I asked this is) is that the property is a reference type, a List of a different class.

Comment: Need lot more cotext and code around this to really understand what is going on.

Comment: Is type of `MyProperty` a value or a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer was yes, because my property is referencing another classes (deserialized from XML) property that is a reference type. The deserialized class hangs around.

Answer (score 1):

The class shouldn't stick around, unless the value of the proprety references back to the class somehow.  The file itself doesn't stick around (unless GetDeserializedFileFromXml does something unexpected).

---

To explain further, if your class is like this:

```
public class MyClass {
   public String MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

then assigning the property to `MyProperty` won't cause `MyClass` to stick around.  If, on the other hand, it's something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        MyProperty = new HoldsAReference(this);
    }
    public HoldsAReference MyProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

then your class will stick around.

Comment: That's my worry. when I do *property = myclass.property* is that assignment maintaining a reference forcing the class to not go away

Answer (score -1):

First thing is for you to understand [Reference and Value types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) works.

From there, it is basic understanding, that **there is no relation between parent object and object inside of any of parent object's properties**. They are completly different entities, that can be anywhere in memory with only reference from one to another.

So if there is even single reference to object in property(except the object, who owns this property), but there is no reference to parent object fron anywhere else, then the parent object will be marked for garbage collection.

Comment: This is not a useful answer. It's condescending and doesn't actually provide a proper answer to the question.

Comment: @Alastair : *(original question)Does doing this keep this deserialized-file-into-a-class-object in memory somewhere.* When Tony Basallo understands, how value and reference types works, then he can easily answer this question.

Comment: Sure, but obviously he doesn't understand and you just telling him to understand doesn't help. Your edit is better, but provide some examples or give more detail if you want to be helpful.

Comment: Actually I do have a **basic** understanding of it...I think the question missed something that you also missed - the property is a reference type. That is my concern.